# InFix to PostFix function Operator don't show

Tags: c, arrays, postfix-notation, infix-operator

```
//Here is the code when I run it operands are displayed but all operators are garbage data. Can you please help me figure it out. 

if (isOperator(expression[i]) == 0)
          {
                  while (((isEmpty() != -1) && (priority(expression[i]) <= priority(stack[getTop()]))))
                  {
                    exp[j++] = expression[i];
                  }
                  push(expression[i]);
          }
```

the while checks if the stack is empty and that the priority of the operator is less or equal than the one of the pre-existing operator.
IsOperator checks if the scanned character is an operator and returns 0 or 1
i is a counter of the for loop that traverses the whole string. And is also the index of the input expression.
j is the index of the output expression

for instance when i enter:  a+b-c*d
expected output: ab+cd*-
Real output: abcd?

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to say what is going on without having more context. What is `isOperator`? What are the other variables? What does it mean "don't show"? What do you mean by "garbage data"? You need to make your question clear enough so that somebody who does not know anything about your code can understand it.

Comment: A function names isXXX should return a true or false value.  Is your true 0 and false -1???

Comment: If I read your `if` statement correctly, it only runs when `expression[i]` is not an operator.

Comment: @stark  true is o and false is -1

Comment: @Commodore63 it only runs when expression[i] is an operator

Comment: @I'mnotacsstudent, by way of convention in C, 0 is false, and not 0 is true.